# "en pos de" vs "tras": Can these be direct synonyms?

Tags: preposiciones

Both "en pos de" and "tras" are prepositions that translate to "after".

In Spanish, are these prepositions direct synonyms. For example, are each of the following sentences proper:

> Fuimos en pos de ella a la otra habitación. (We went after her to the other room.)
>
> Fuimos tras ella a la otra habitación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are synonyms, however `en pos` is not very common on everyday spoken language.

Here a copy from [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=pos)

pos. en pos. Esta locución se usa hoy seguida de un complemento con de, con valor preposicional análogo a **tras** (‘`en seguimiento de` o `en busca de`’):

> «Llevo muchos años en pos de la verdad» (Cerezales Escaleras [Esp. 1991]).

El complemento puede ser un pronombre personal (`en pos de mí`, `en pos de él`, etc.):

> «La joven lo siguió y subió en pos de él hasta el desván» (Jodorowsky Pájaro [Chile 1992]);

Pero **no** debe usarse con posesivos (en pos mío, en pos suyo, etc.):

«En pos suyo arrastra a toda una nación» (Universal [Ven.] 17.4.88); debió decirse `en pos de sí`.

Comment: Thanks, @DGaleano. I'm studying Spanish prepositions, and find that so many of them translate to the same English word(s). It helps me to know which words are direct synonyms, so I'll be posting more questions like this whenever I find myself stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct form:

> Fuimos tras ella a la otra habitación.

Because "en pos" is never used for subjects.

Comment: ¿Por qué? es bueno indicar una explicación para que tu respuesta sea de mayor utilidad.

Comment: Thanks, David.

Well, from the online dictionary WordReference.com, the entry for "en pos de" offers as an example the sentence that appears in my original post. Therefore the implication is that it's indeed proper to use "en pos de" for subjects.

However, David, methinks you would know better than me. :)